# Highcharts - `lineColor` doesn't work with Zone

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have issue with `lineColor` using `zone` in `series`

I have example where `lineColor` is implemented and working fine. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4xofqpra/)

But when i use `zone` then `lineColor` disappears. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bqsfx9r3/)

Its very strange...

Comment: does this thing work for you. http://jsfiddle.net/bqsfx9r3/2/

Comment: this will resolve my issue, but there is no direct way..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played around a bit with the different settings allowed for `areasplines` while looking at the API and found that if you set:

```
color: 'red', 
fillColor: colors[2]
```

for each individual `zone`, you can get the `lineColor` to look like your first example, but with zones. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bqsfx9r3/3/)